# How to install Cyanogenmod on Huawei IDEOS U8150?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, huawei-u8150

I am installing a custom rom for the very first time and I simply don't want to brick my phone (Huawei U8150).

1. I downloaded and installed Rom Manager
2. I downloaded Cyanogen 7 (update-cm-7.2.0-RC0-U8150-KANG-signed-dec5.zip) for my U8150 and stored it on SD card.
3. I started Rom Manager > Flash ClockMod Recovery > shows a list of supported phones. *It does not have U8150 in the list.* I wonder how others have made it work!
4. From ROM Manager I chosen the Rom file manually with "Install ROM from SD Card" option, it restarts and gives only for options a. reboot, b. apply update.zip c & d. wipe

What to do next? The rom file is in .zip, while I downloaded another .img file (clockworkmod_5.0.2.7_u8150.img). What does it exactly do?

I think i must first create backup of current rom and then install cyanogen.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install ClockworkMod Recovery using any of the given methods [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1053704):

   > - Install Terminal Emulator from the market.
   > - Install Root Explorer from the market.
   > - [Download](http://www.mediafire.com/?fjac93mns5exdaq) the recovery of your choice and copy the recovery.img to your sd card. (if its not named recovery.img rename it)
   > - With Root Explorer, navigate to where the recovery is and copy it to /system/bin/ (remember to select mount as R/W first in order for it to copy.)
   > - Open Terminal Emulator and enter the command "su" (without the quotes)
   > - After that enter the command "flash_image recovery /system/bin/recovery.img" (again without the quotes)
   > - That's it, the recovery has been flashed. Reboot in recovery to confirm.
   > - Once you've confirmed the recovery flashed properly remember to delete the recovery.img from /system/bin/ (using root explorer, and mount as R/W)
2. Then follow the instructions of using ClockworkMod given [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-clockworkmod-recovery-and-how-to-use-it-on-android-complete-guide/)

Comment: Why the downvote? The first link has step-by-step instructions on how to correctly flash the recovery.

Comment: @Chahk: Your edit is not correct, because that link has three different methods, the second one worked for me.

Comment: Any one of the 3 methods should work.  Feel free to edit again with the method that worked for you though.